# In Java , would there be a performance hit if I just always imported all the main libraries?

Tags: java, import

Is there a downside to starting every java program with *all* the imports? This would prevent me having to recall which import I need.

Could I simply start the java code with

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
//etc
```

What is the downside to coding this way?

Comment: No, regarding runtime performance, it is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Holger - Ok understood,  thanks !!